# New WD 6TB drives shows as 0MB in BIOS

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I have a Shuttle XPC SX58J3 which came with a WD 1TB HDD. I bought it in about 2010.

I'm trying to replace the HDD with a 250GB SSD (for the OS and applications) plus a WD 6TB HDD (for the home directories).

I've successfully removed the 1TB drive, put it in a USB SATA caddy and verified that I can access the data from another machine. I've also successfully mounted the SSD and the new HDD in the internal drive caddy which had three spaces (one for the DVD drive, one for the SSD and one for the HDD).

I then booted up the machine and, after some time, I got an error about "3rd master hard disk error". I see the following:

```
Auto-Detecting ......Hard Disk:WDC WD60EFZX-68B3FN0
Auto-Detecting ......Hard Disk:CT250MX500SSD1  M3CR043
Auto-Detecting ......CDROM:HL-DT-ST BDDVDRW CH10LS20  1.00

3rd Master Hard Disk Error
```

In the BIOS configuration, I can see the WDC drive in Serial ATA 1 Channel and the Crucial SSD in Serial ATA 3 Channel.

But when I drill down into the details for the WDC drive it says:

```
Device    :Hard Disk
Vendor    :WDC WD60EFZX-68B3FN0
Size      :0MB
LBA Mode  :Not Supported
Block Mode:Not Supporrted
S.M.A.R.T.:Not Supported
```

Then in the Boot settings, it shows only the Crucial SSD.

I tried switching the SATA mode to AHCI. When I do this, I see the BIOS trying to detect disks with the message:

```
Auto-Detecting AHCI Port 0..Hard Disk:
Auto-Detecting AHCI Port 1..Hard Disk:
Auto-Detecting AHCI Port 3..CDROM:

AHCI Port0 Device Error
```

With AHCI enabled, in the BIOS configuration, it shows no disks the IDE settings. But in the Boot settings, it shows both disks.

I've tried using a new cable for the WD 6TB drive and also plugging that new cable into a different socket. The only thing that changed was the reported port that the WD drive was connected to. It still says it's 0MB.

My plan would be to install Debian Linux on the SSD and make it mount the 6TB HDD as `/home`. I've tried just continuing with the Debian installer and it offers only the SSD when it gets to the partitioning step. I guess this is expected. I also tried running `fdisk -l` in the installer and I can see that it only finds the SSD and the USB drive that contains the installer.

Any suggestions why this drive is showing as 0MB and is not visible to the Debian installer?

Comment: Well, it obviously is too large, no? Every bit costs money, so S-ATA controllers often do not fully support the standard. You should check which S-ATA controller you have (most likely chipset-integrated) and what it can do.

Comment: @DanielB thanks for this. Any suggestions how I might be able to find out which SATA controller it is? Can I do it from the BIOS? Or from the Debian installer? Or will I have to put the original HDD back in so I have a proper OS to work with? The online specs for this machine say "(4) on board 3.0Gb/s bandwidth SATA (RAID 0,1,10,5)". That implies SATA II, but maybe that's not what you mean.

Comment: @ironchicken - It's a controller from 12 years ago, then the limitation of the controller, explains the behavior you describe. Since you can't replace the controller on the board, there are not a lot of solutions, outside of a PCIe SATA board. However, it's often the case, disks connected to such a board cannot be booted to.  You will need to get a smaller drive.

Comment: I see it mentioned here that it supports up to 2TB. https://global.shuttle.com/news/productsNewsDetail?newsId=1162&productId=1389

Comment: First I would verify if the new WB drive works at all. Try to using it in a different PC or the USB SATA adapter and then boot a live Linux system. If it works try to create a primary partition of less than 2TB and check if your PC BIOS then is able to see the disk.

Comment: I suspect the issue is not that the controller does not support thr standard, but that the drive is larger then 2TB.   Drives larger then 2TB are to big tosupport the older MBR standard....

Comment: According to https://global.shuttle.com/products/productsFaqDetail?faqId=2037 there may be newer firmware you can flash to supercede the 2tb limit.

Comment: MBR or not is not relevant to disk detection. However, further research reveals the misdetection should make it show up as ~1.5 TB, not 0 MB. Either way, this SATA controller apparently does not support Logical Block Addresses larger than 32 bit. I’ll look some more.

Comment: So it sounds like the problem is that the SATA controller doesn't support >2TB drives. I also read somewhere about 5-wire SATA power cables possibly sending WD Red drives to sleep. If there's power on the orange wire it apparently instructs NAS drives to sleep.